# I deploy my spring project to get jar file I can't access the external jar that is working during run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, plugins

In my project A I have a dependent external jar for example jar B
when I run this command  `mvn clean install` to deploy jar file of A

```
[ERROR]   symbol:   class WebSocket
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.WebSocketProtocolSub
[ERROR]   /C:/Users/user/Documents/projects/B/src/main/java/com/example/B/WebSocketProtocolSub.java:[140,31] cannot find symbol
```

unfortunately I can't share the repo but I can explain it again
I have external jar is called for example "dependent.jar"
I used many classes from this jar & it is working during running on IDE
but when try to deploy it using mvn clean install
I got this error that mean it can't find the dependent classes from this jar
& I don't have the source code of the dependent jar

Comment: It is hard to know what is happening. Do you have source in the public repo such as github?

Comment: unfortunately I can't share the repo but I can explain it again
I have external jar is called for example "dependent.jar" 
I used many classes from this jar & it is working during running on IDE
but when try to deploy it using mvn clean install
I got this error that mean it can't find the dependent classes from this jar
& I don't have the source code of the dependent jar

Comment: if it's working in IDE and not while running mvn command it can mean that your IDE have embedded maven which have different settings

Comment: but when I add external jar it must be included during deployment 
is should I make repackaging for dependent package

Comment: Are you using the  spring-boot-maven-plugin? It builds an executeable fat jar with all dependencies. For further info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/